# Ruby on Rails(Form submit)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models User and Business. There is no association between them how can I show attributes of them in one single view with one submit.

Comment: Do you want a single form that has fields for 2 unrelated models or something else?

Comment: User `form_tag` to generate a general form with input field names like `user[name]`, `business[address]`, etc. Then create a new controller where you receive your form data and update those.

Comment: I didn't get it. My User fields are working right

Comment: I want to add fields for business model. But I am having difficulty in that.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your form like this, where question_path is where you are going to post, for e.g. I have two models question and bug and I have defined them as such

```
<%= form_tag(questions_path, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= text_field_tag 'question[name]' %><br>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= text_field_tag 'bug[title]' %><br>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @PrafullPurwar consider upvoting and setting the answer as correct if it solved your problem.